# R foreach loop - package load fails

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm unable to load any packages to parallel processes in a foreach %dopar% loop.

I successfully create 4 SOCK clusters using the foreach and doSNOW packages, then try to run a trivial parallel process. It works with %dopar% without using any packages, but loading an arbitrary package throws an error.

Sample code below, followed by session info showing the packages in use.

I have used this type of code before without issues. Some recent network changes at my company meant I had to change some settings (default library path, etc), may be related to that change. Not sure where to start in troubleshooting what the issue is - any help greatly appreciated!

```
#load foreach and doSNOW packages, setup 4 clusters#

> require(foreach)

> require(doSNOW)

> registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK"))

> getDoParWorkers()
[1] 4

> getDoParName()
[1] "doSNOW"

# %dopar% loop without loading any packages -- works OK #

> foreach(i=1:2) %dopar%

{
    i+1
}

[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

# %dopar% loop with loading a package -- does not work #

> foreach(i=1:2,.packages="forecast") %dopar%

  {

      i+1

  }

Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  worker initialization failed: package or namespace load failed for        'forecast'
```

Session Info:
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] WriteXLS_3.6.1     rlist_0.4          timeSeries_3012.99 reshape2_1.4.1     plyr_1.8.3         lubridate_1.3.3    lmtest_0.9-34      lattice_0.20-31    knitr_1.10.5
[10] hts_4.5            Matrix_1.2-1       SparseM_1.6        ggplot2_1.0.1      data.table_1.9.4   car_2.0-25         forecast_6.1       timeDate_3012.100  zoo_1.7-12
[19] doSNOW_1.0.12      snow_0.3-13        iterators_1.0.7    foreach_1.4.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.6      compiler_3.2.1   nloptr_1.0.4     tseries_0.10-34  tools_3.2.1      lme4_1.1-8       digest_0.6.8     memoise_0.2.1    gtable_0.1.2     nlme_3.1-120
[11] mgcv_1.8-6       parallel_3.2.1   proto_0.3-10     stringr_1.0.0    grid_3.2.1       nnet_7.3-9       minqa_1.2.4      magrittr_1.5     scales_0.2.5     codetools_0.2-11
[21] MASS_7.3-40      splines_3.2.1    pbkrtest_0.4-2   colorspace_1.2-6 fracdiff_1.4-2   quantreg_5.11    quadprog_1.5-5   stringi_0.5-5    munsell_0.4.2    chron_2.3-47

Other info that may be useful- .libPaths() location and the details from the makeCluster function.

```
> .libPaths()
 [1] "C:/Users/G082580/Documents/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1" "C:/R-3.2.1/library"                               

> makeCluster(4,type="SOCK",manual=TRUE)
```

Manually start worker on localhost with
     C:/R-32~1.1/bin/Rscript.exe "C:/Users/G082580/Documents/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/snow/RSOCKnode.R" MASTER=localhost PORT=11535 OUT=/dev/null SNOWLIB=C:/Users/G082580/Documents/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1

Comment: What directory is forecast installed in? And are you using any mechanism to add a directory to your .libPath?

Comment: Steve -

I set .libPaths to a local directory, same location as the package.

 `code`   > .libPaths("C:/Users/G082580/Documents/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1")

   > install.packages("forecast")

    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/G082580/Documents/My      Documents/R/R-3.2.1’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
   The downloaded binary packages are in
     C:\Users\G082580\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEPdckz\downloaded_packages `code`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use the `.libPaths` function in order to load packages on the master, you'll need to call it on the workers as well. This example uses the `clusterCall` function to initialize the workers to be the same as the master:

```
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(4)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
clusterCall(cl, function(x) .libPaths(x), .libPaths())
```